# Express Mysql getting max ID from table not working cought in a promise

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to add a worker and then his id and name go to another table to work with

this doesnt work I tried it

```
router.post('/add_employee', (req, res) => {
    // Insert into puntoretuji table
    const sql = "INSERT INTO puntoretuji (name, salary, role) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [req.body.name, req.body.salary, req.body.role];

     con.query(sql, [values], (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ Status: false, Error: "Query Error" });
      return res.json({ Status: true});

      
    });

  }


);

router.post('/worker_id', (req, res) => {


    
  const query = `SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM puntoretuji`;
  const values = [req.body.id]

  const result = con.query(query, values)
  const maxId = result[0].max_id;



    // Insert into worker_data table
    const insertWorkerDataQuery = "INSERT INTO worker_data (worker_id, name) VALUES (?)";
    const workerDataValues = [maxId, req.body.name]; // Assuming current date for 'date'

    con.query(insertWorkerDataQuery, workerDataValues);
  }
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is not a good description of what happened.

Comment: I do not see any await or other code to wait for the query promise to be finished